# How can I retrieve unique values from a column with Knex.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I use [Knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) to communicate to Postgres database.

I have rows in a table with a column named 'state' which represents a US state.

How can I retrieve all unique values from this column?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are probably looking for [knex.distinct](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#distinct) + [knex.pluck](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#pluck) combo.

```
knex
    .distinct()
    .from('tablename')
    .pluck('state')
    .then(states => {
        console.log(states)
    })
```

Comment: @milan No, it's not. This builder gives a valid query `select distinct "state" from "tablename"`. You can try it yourself with `console.log(knex.distinct().from('tablename').pluck('state').toString());`.

Comment: hm, seems like you're right, i was fooled by the logger which showed entire records in the console

Comment: Links point to the same home page

Comment: @JRichardsz, I've fixed that now

Comment: your query would work however you likely want to add a `whereNotNull('state')` and pass `state` to `distinct()` as well