# How to translate SELECT DISTINCT ON to knex.js

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I am having a trouble translating DISTINCT ON clause to knex.js
and there might also couple of errors along the way with multiple andOn inside join().
Could not find ways to translate it properly.

```
select DISTINCT ON (f1.operdate) f1.operdate as date,
  f2.operdate as opendate,
  opercodes.naenter code hereme as name,
  f1.person as person,
  f1.comments as comments,
  f2.person as conductor    
from cashboxdiary as f1
inner join opercodes on (opercodes.id = f1.opercode)
inner join cashboxdiary f2 on (f2.company = f1.company and f2.cashbox = f1.cashbox and f2.opercode = 3 and f2.operdate < f1.operdate)
```

What I have tried so far

```
knex("cashboxdiary")
.innerJoin("opercodes", "opercodes.id", "cashboxdiary.opercode")
.join('cashboxdiary as f2',function () {
    this.on('f2.company','=','cashboxdiary.company')
    .andOn('f2.cashbox','=','cashboxdiary.cashbox')
    .andOn('f2.opercode','=',knex.raw('?',[3]))
    .andOn('f2.operdate','<','cashboxdiary.operdate');      
})
.where({ "cashboxdiary.company": company, "cashboxdiary.cashbox": cashbox})
.whereNotIn("cashboxdiary.opercode", [3, 4, 5, 6])
.andWhereBetween(knex.raw("cashboxdiary.operdate::date"), [
  dateFrom.format(),
  dateTo.format()
])
.select(knex.raw('distinct on (cashboxdiary.operdate) cashboxdiary.operdate as date,f2.operdate as opendate, opercode.name as name, cashboxdiary.person as person, cashboxdiary.comments as comments, f2.person as conductor'))
```

Comment: Your query uses `distinct on` without `order by`.  That makes the results indeterminate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  There is a `order by f1.operdate, f2.operdate desc` I just forgot to include it. But my problem is not with query it is with knex.

Comment: sorry for mess ups it is my first question though ) be gentle with aha

Comment: I have figured out the answer. It was syntax problem.

Comment: At last line I just should have knex.rawed only distinct on. Like so:
`.select(knex.raw('distinct on (cashboxdiary.operdate) cashboxdiary.operdate as date), 'f2.operdate as opendate', 'opercode.name'...`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263583/how-can-i-retrieve-unique-values-from-a-column-with-knex-js